# "ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" when running .class directly from command line

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, sqljdbc

I know this has been asked a million times, I looked up 100's of links all point to what I am doing, but I am not able to get this working.

Code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class ConnectMSSQLServer
{
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection conn = null;
        String dbName = "database1";
        String serverip="dv-bi-olap1";
        String serverport="1433";
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" + "databaseName=AdventureWorks;user=MyUserName;password=*****;";
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
        String databaseUserName = "admin";
        String databasePassword = "root";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            result = null;
            String pa,us;
            result = stmt.executeQuery("select * from table1 ");

            while (result.next()) {
                us=result.getString("uname");
                pa = result.getString("pass");              
                System.out.println(us+"  "+pa);
            }

            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

CMD commands:

```
C:\Users\blabla\Desktop>javac ConnectMSSQLServer.java
```

class file is created

```
set CLASSPATH =.;C:\Users\blabla\Desktop\sqljdbc_4.2\enu\sqljdbc42.jar

C:\Users\blabla\Desktop>java ConnectMSSQLServer

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at ConnectMSSQLServer.main(ConnectMSSQLServer.java:21)
```

ok that dint work, so i tried below

```
C:\Users\blabla\Desktop>java -CLASSPATH =.;C:\Users\blabla\Desktop\sqljdbc_4.2\enu\sqljdbc42.jar -cp . ConnectMSSQLServer
```

then this

```
C:\Users\blabla\Desktop>java -CLASSPATH =.;C:\Users\blabla\Desktop\sqljdbc_4.2\enu\sqljdbc42.jar ConnectMSSQLServer
```

all resulted in the below error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at ConnectMSSQLServer.main(ConnectMSSQLServer.java:21)
```

Comment: Open "sqljdbc42.jar" with a tool that can open zip files (like winzip). Does it contain "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"?

Comment: This is a Q&A site. "HELP!!!!" is not a question. Also, why are you trying to command-line (or edit by hand) the classpath? Use an IDE like netbeans or eclipse; it will get things ready for you, including your configs.

Comment: Occam's Razor: the path to the driver jar is simply wrong. Prove that it isn't. All the tests that you post here assume that the path is correct and that there is something wrong with how Java is invoked.

Comment: @Gimby ... and the question is misleading because `-CLASSPATH` simply does not work at all. It's not a matter of the code throwing a ClassNotFoundException, it's a matter of the `java` command failing with "Unrecognized option: -CLASSPATH". (That is, the `java` command doesn't even *begin* to run the code.)

Comment: @GordThompson true, but the one test where the classpath is set as a CLASSPATH environmental variable should have worked

Comment: Sorry about adding HELP!! I was loosing my mind for something this simple.

Comment: I restarted the computer and it worked. FACEPALM

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the `=` & using lowercase `classpath` (or `cp`) option

```
java -classpath .;C:\Users\blabla\Desktop\sqljdbc_4.2\enu\sqljdbc42.jar ConnectMSSQLServer
```

Comment: I had tried this, it did not work, I am going to use netbeans and try and get this working

Comment: are you getting the same exception message?

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the driver.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx

Then include it in your application. Based on what you are saying I cannot see that you have the driver you need to use JBDC with you application.

Comment: The drivers are downloaded from this site